# Removes values of one array from another

Tags: php, arrays

Say I have these two array:

```
$arraryA = array(10587,10590,10598,10592,10602,10604,10607);

$arrayB = array(10590);
```

What I know, is that,

1. values of $arrayB will always be elements from $arrayA
2. $arrayB may have one or more elements

I need to remove the values of $arrayB from $arrayA.

Means, I need a new array as:

$arrayC = array(10587,10598,10592,10602,10604,10607);

if `$arrayB = array(10590, 10604)`, $arrayC will be:

```
$arrayC = array(10587,10598,10592,10602,10607);
```

Any idea ?

Comment: You've not though to look at array_diff() then?

Comment: That's it Mark. How can I accept your reply ? Can you post a new reply please so that I can accept it ?

Comment: Question, do I need to check if $arrayB is present as an array with array_diff, or that checks it automatically ?

Comment: I can't recall if the second argument passed to array_diff() must be an array, but suspect that this is probably the case

Comment: Right, I checked it. $arrayB must be present as an array, else it throws error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array_diff()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

```
$arrayC= array_diff($arrayA, $arrayB);
```

**Example**:

```
$arrayA = array(10587,10590,10598,10592,10602,10604,10607);
$arrayB  = array(10590);
$arrayC  = array_diff($arrayA, $arrayB);

var_dump($arrayC);

// array(6) { [0]=> int(10587) [2]=> int(10598) [3]=> int(10592) [4]=> int(10602) [5]=> int(10604) [6]=> int(10607) }
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/gthuPV)